Pandas Dataframe apply function multiple columns
  product_code  base_price    promo_type  q_bef  q_aft
0          P11         190       50% OFF     34     52
1          P03         156       25% OFF    393    322
2          P07         300         BOGOF     22     85
3          P15        3000  500 Cashback    329   1000
4          P05          55       25% OFF    108     93

Table has data of products and base_price,promo_type,quantity_before_sold and quantity_before_sold
we need to find the  total revenue before applying promo
for eg:sum(base_price*q_bef)
and we need to find the total revenue after promo
for eg:
promo_type=='50% OFF' , base_price/2
promo_type=='25% OFF' , base_price/4
then calculate total revenue with new base_price and q_aft
please let me know how to do in pandas Data frame using differnt functions
Total Revenue before and after

Assuming you want to modify the price based on the "% OFF" (base_price * (1-PERCENT/100) and for example based on the "CASHBACK" (base_price - CASHBACK), you could first extract each promo, then perform arithmetic:
factor = (df['promo_type'].str.extract(r'(\d+)%', expand=False)
          .astype(float).div(100).rsub(1).fillna(1)
         )

cashback = df['promo_type'].str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*Cashback', expand=False,
                                        flags=re.I).astype(float).fillna(0)

df['revenue'] = df['base_price'].mul(factor).sub(cashback).mul(df['q_bef'])

Output:
  product_code  base_price    promo_type  q_bef  q_aft   revenue
0          P11         190       50% OFF     34     52    3230.0
1          P03         156       25% OFF    393    322   45981.0
2          P07         300         BOGOF     22     85    6600.0
3          P15        3000  500 Cashback    329   1000  822500.0
4          P05          55       25% OFF    108     93    4455.0

Then to get the total revenue:
df['revenue'].sum()
# 882766

Intermediates:
# factor
0    0.50
1    0.75
2    1.00
3    1.00
4    0.75
Name: promo_type, dtype: float64

# cashback
0      0.0
1      0.0
2      0.0
3    500.0
4      0.0
Name: promo_type, dtype: float64

